# Converting a PE executable to a RAW format

Tags: metasploit

I am on a red team exercise and want to try `wePWNise` to create a malware document with an executable that I have created and tested and know to pass the target's AV.

Does anybody know how to convert a PE executable back to raw in the format that you would get from `msfvenom -f raw` set? Is there a script, tool, or something that does this?

Comment: You want to decompile the executable?

Comment: Not a decompile. More like getting a raw or bin file as output by msfvenom -f raw

Comment: "convert a PE executable back to raw in the format" -- that really sounds like decompiling. You can't take a compiled executable and "convert" it.

Comment: No, it's not a decompile... it is converting it to a bin (binary raw) format. Is that a decompile to binary? Anyways, figured out how to do that with a Python script for creating payloads to inject as DLL. It converts a DLL or exe to bin. I would share the script here, but actually picked it up through a malware dev course I took a year ago.